# Tests not working (Rails 5.1.4 and paperclip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having trouble running any test using "rake test".

This is the error I am getting

```
# Running:

E

Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_the_truth:
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: posts.image_file_name: INSERT INTO "posts" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2018-03-10 10:40:55.109886', '2018-03-10 10:40:55.109886', 980190962)
```

Honestly, I have no idea why there is an insert because the request is not even getting there.

This is my test but as I said none of the tests are working so it really doesn't matter what I put in there.

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end

end
```

And my route just to make sure I am not missing anything.

```
  match "/posts(/:action(/:id))", to: "posts#posts", via: [:GET,:POST]
```

Also my migration

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.attachment :image #I used to have null: false here but I removed it and deleted dbs
      t.text :description
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What's on your db/schema.rb?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your posts.yml fixtures file. Based on your migration, posts *must* have a value for the image_file_name column, which probably isn’t present if you’ve modified that model via a migration.